# iOS 6 What is the standard way to deal with background saving of managed objects (in 2013)?

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-data, restkit, magicalrecord

Last year I used RestKit 0.10 to seamlessly download and save core data objects in background. However, when I tried to use restkit in 2013, I noticed that they have taken out the ActiveRecord pattern, which I relied upon to abstract away all the unpleasantness of background saving.

I found that the ActiveRecord pattern exists in MagicalRecord framework, but most of the documentation I could find is for version 2.x, while my cocoapods install 3.x.

I spent the last 2 hours searching, and find a lot of answers that are really out of date and no longer work for these new frameworks.

This poses the question: **what the standard/easiest way to deal with saving core data objects in background using frameworks available in 2013?** Should I try some other framework?

Comment: RestKit still loads and saves everything on background threads...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't use any external library like Magical Record or RestKit, but simply go for the all manual stuff, you can take advantage of the new `NSManagedObjectContext` APIs.

You can now have contexts nested with a parent-child relationship and you can also tell each context to perform a block in it's own thread. My advice, therefore is to have the following structure for your application:

1) A background saving context. This will be the only context that saves and reads data directly to/from the database.

2) A context initalized on the main thread that will be your point of access for everything you need to do in the application, especially updating the UI. This context will be a child of the saving context.

3) As needed, you'll create background contextes that perform work on background threads, e.g. loading data from the network and serialize this data in NSManagedObject instances. This contextes will be children of the main context.

4) Every time you call `-[NSManagedObjectContext save:]` on a context, you should also call the same method on it's parentContext. To do this you could have a convenience method in a category on NSManagedObjectContext that reads something like this:

```
- (void)saveSelfAndParent {
    [self save:NULL];
    [self.parentContext performBlock:^{
        [self.parentContext saveSelfAndParent];
    }];
}
```

This is already a thread safe configuration and your changes will propagate the changes up to the database. Note that as the saving context will have no parent (and thus self.parentContext will be nil), the performBlock: won't crash the app.

Here's an example what you need to do to create a new entity assuming you kick off your background work using Grand Central Dispatch (GCD):

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_async_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType: NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
    context.parentContext = mainContext;

    // do some expensive job
    ...

    // initialize a new NSManagedObject instance using the information we calculated
    NSManagedObject *myObject = ...;

    // once we're done, let's save the context
    [context saveSelfAndParent];
});
```

Note that we initialized the context with a private queue concurrency type (NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType) which tells the context that he's a background context. That is very important!

That's all! :)

For more information refer to the [NSManagedObjectContext Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html).

Comment: Great suggestion for Mac! On iOS, I found https://github.com/jksk/NLCoreData , which in preliminary testing seems to work fine. It also has only two contexts - main and background with methods to save each one in a nested fashion.